# arraylist is emptied after the method is run

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist, android-recyclerview, listener

I am trying to fill an array list with data but it gets emptied after the method is complete

I am supposed to get items into a recyclerview however the data to be displayed cannot be displayed if my array list since it is emptied after the method is done
however the items are displayed when the phone back light goes off and I bring it back on

if I

```java
Log.d("TAG",mScheduleNames.get(0));
```

within the on complete method I get an output

However if I output it before the firebase user, I get a null point exception which runs after the method... 
The data within the arraystring seems to have been emptied

```java
public class Schedules extends Fragment {


    private static final String TAG = "AddingEvents";

    private ArrayList<String> mScheduleNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mScheduleImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private int i;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedules, container, false);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        final FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        i = 0;
        db.collection("Schedules")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                if (document.get("Owner").toString().equals(currentUser.getUid())){
                                    mScheduleNames.add(document.get("Schedule").toString());
                                    mScheduleImageUrls.add("https://www.crockerriverside.org/sites/main/files/imagecache/square/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg");
                                    i++;
                                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                                }
                            }
                            if(i == 0){
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You do not have any existing schedules. \r\n " +
                                        "Click on add schedule at the bottom", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "About to display your schedules ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error getting your schedules.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.w(TAG, "Error getting your schedules.", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });


        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviews);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this.getContext(), mScheduleNames, mScheduleImageUrls);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));

        /*
        mScheduleNames.add("Steve");
        mScheduleImageUrls.add("https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/5718897981_10faa45ac3_b-640x624.jpg");

        mScheduleNames.add("Bella");
        mScheduleImageUrls.add("https://www.crockerriverside.org/sites/main/files/imagecache/square/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg");

        mScheduleNames.add("Carre");
        mScheduleImageUrls.add("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5b/Ultraviolet_image_of_the_Cygnus_Loop_Nebula_crop.jpg/691px-Ultraviolet_image_of_the_Cygnus_Loop_Nebula_crop.jpg");
        */
    }
}
```

I expect the data to be displayed in the recycler view.

Comment: Everything in the `OnCompleteListener` will be executed _asynchronously_, which means that when you call `new RecyclerViewAdapter(...)` the lists haven't been populated yet. You can call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` at the end of your `onComplete()` callback in order to tell the adapter that the data has been updated.

Comment: Thank you this totally worked... 
I would like to know more about asynchronous and synchronous execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you Ben P
This worked

```java
db.collection("Schedules")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                if (document.get("Owner").toString().equals(currentUser.getUid())){
                                    mScheduleNames.add(document.get("Schedule").toString());
                                    mScheduleImageUrls.add("https://www.crockerriverside.org/sites/main/files/imagecache/square/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg");
                                    i++;
                                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                                }
                            }
                            if(i == 0){
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You do not have any existing schedules. \r\n " +
                                        "Click on add schedule at the bottom", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "About to display your schedules ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error getting your schedules.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.w(TAG, "Error getting your schedules.", task.getException());
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
```